# Store some options in web

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

I am designing a web portal , and in some of its pages , I have a javascript grid(includes pager). I want to store last page that the user visits , and to doing something like this, I think I should use Cookies and javascript (or maybe jquery)

*FYI , my grid is FlexGrid and as you know FlexGrid is created by jquery*

Is there anyone out there to help me about this stuff ? any idea can be usefull

Sorry about my bad english syntax(I am new)

**UPDATE 1** : As I tagged my question , I am using Asp.net (C#) and MSSQL 2008 as database engine

Comment: What server side language are you using to write the database code in? PHP? ASP.NET? Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to you could certainly [set a cookie on the client using JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Cookies).

You could also [set cookies using ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (but that would be more work).

You could also use [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), and [fall back to cookies](https://gist.github.com/350433) for older browsers.

As you can see you have lots of options here. The one you pick depends on your needs, but from what you have described I would go with a library that uses HTML5 storage first, and then falls back to cookies for older browsers.

Comment: Thanks , after checking the links, I decide to use fall back , and thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx. It should work as long as the user clicked a link to get the current page.